# How do I copy/move a directory with tons of content from EXT4?

Tags: filesystems, directory, file-copy

So I have a Micro-SD card with an EXT4 file system on it. On there are a bunch of files that I used to save in this structure: `/YYYY-MM/folders/files` - The amount of files in the `folders` is usually just 1-10, but the amount of `folders` in `YYYY-MM` is a lot. I have now changed it to `YYYY-MM/YYYY-MM-DD/..` to keep it nicer, but...

I need to copy/move all the files off of the µSD card. This worked for every folder except `2019-10` which I assume contains too many folders. Commands that failed (not all for moving):

- `rsync` (over ssh): After ~2 days of "receiving incremental file list", it disconnected
- `mv`: It creates the directory in DEST, then gets stuck
- `cp`: Same thing, stuck at `./2019-10/ -> DEST/2019-10/`
- `find .`: Nothing for an hour, I CTRL+C'd after
- `ls`: Same as above
- `du -chs 2019-10`: I let this one run for around 3 days, nothing

The size of `2019-10` is around 15.5GB (determined by `df -h` after everything else was moved off). The amount of `folders` (I know because a database of the folders exists) in `2019-10` is 40472. Each of those has ~4 files on average inside.

Now my question is: How can I move all these folders out of there?

Btw: At first I thought the µSD-Card had issues and that's why I can't read the directory, but moving `2019-11` and `2019-12` worked just fine at normal speed. They both contained the same amount of files in total, but due to better structure they never had more than ~2000 folders in a single directory.

Side info: 32GB SanDisk A1 µSD-Card (no counterfeit), internal laptop SD Card reader (performs best), debian 10 OS (arch available), 8GB RAM and a 4x3.2GHz i7 CPU.

---

As I was writing this question, I realized a solution (happens so often it's crazy). I made a script that goes through the database and for every folder entry retrieves the name of the folder and then does a `mv -v /sd-card/2019-10/${folderid}/ DEST` to move it. Works perfectly fine at normal speed.

I still ask this question and want to know what to do in case I wouldn't have the database, this might be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Sounds like the SD card is dead.  Unable to read blocks from the directory tree and just hanging.  Do you have a backup?

Comment: @PhilipCouling Please see the bottom part of my question on my solution for my specific case. The script finished with an avg. speed of 10MB/s which is definitely fine. The data is all there. I'm just interested if there is a solution in case someone else does not have a database with the foldernames to do what I did. Since my solution worked, I'm 99% sure the card is fine.

Comment: Actually... I just checked if I can use `ls` or `find` or anything on the SD card... The card is now pretty much empty (`df -h` checked) and the `2019-10` directory should be completely empty, however both `ls` and `find .` hang right at that folder still.... Weird. I can do a re-format with no problem since I saved all the data now, but an explanation would still be cool. Seems strange to me. The card itself should really be fine, it's just been in use for a few months and SanDisk's always been a very solid brand for me.

Comment: Okay, my bad. This was an ext4 filesystem, not FAT32. I have ran `fsck.ext4 -f -y`, after which the issue disappeared. A lot of Inode ref counts have been fixed and a bunch of filetypes have been set.

Comment: ah that makes more sense.  ext4 is much less constained than fat32.  I was going to suggest trying `ls -U` since `ls` can perform slowly with directories over 1000 files.  But usually that doesn't make it "hang for an hour".  And yes minor corruption on the file system can mess things up.  Always try to eject SD cards properly.  If you are manually mounting on the file system then always call `sync` between unmounting and removing the card.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Indeed, that card has weirdly never been unmounted, the issue must've appeared while it was mounted. Not quite sure why. Until now, the card was just been written to, never any other operation, no read, no delete. If you want to you can leave a full answer for me to accept. Maybe you can add some information beyond "just run fsck", if you happen to know what could cause this (given what I said at the beginning of this comment)